# How to customize p5.js default loading animation in preload()?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

In p5.js, when you load images/sounds using the `preload` function, a default loading screen is shown. It looks like this:

[image: image depicting p5.js's default loading screen]

This is fine, but in my game, this text blends in with the black background of my game, and I feel as though the player might think the game is broken if the game takes too long to load, since they are seeing a pure black screen. I want to be able to replace this loading screen with my own, so it is actually indicated to the player that the game is loading.

I tried looking through the p5.js documentation, but couldn't find anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please note that I'm new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the docs](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/preload):

> By default the text "loading..." will be displayed. To make your own loading page, include an HTML element with id "p5_loading" in your page. More information [here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/p5.js-overview#loading-screen).

Go to the "here" link and see:

> #### Loading Screen
>
> As mentioned above, if your sketch has large media dependencies such as images, audio or videos, these should be loaded into your sketch using the `preload()` function. Since loading large files can take some time, you might want to display a loading screen to your users. This will convey that your sketch is indeed running — it just has a lot of cool things to load first. To add a loading screen to your p5.js sketch, all you need to do is include an HTML element on your page with the id `p5_loading`. It would look something like the following:
>
> ```html
> <div id="p5_loading" class="loadingclass">
>   this could be some sweet > graphics loading lots of bits.
> </div>
> ```
>
> P5.js looks through your HTML to see if you have included an element with the id `p5_loading`. P5.js will use this element and its content as the loading screen for your sketch. Since the loading element is included in your HTML, you can add any additional classes and/or style the element anyway you see fit.

Example:

```js
let img;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage(`https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?cache=${random()}`);
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1000, 1000);
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  image(img, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.js"></script>
<h1 id="p5_loading">
  Custom loading element
</h1>
```

If that doesn't work for your use case, you can always bypass P5 and add some arbitrary vanilla DOM element that p5 will remove, or do your loading from `setup()` per this tip from the [docs link](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/preload):

> If asynchronous loading is preferred, the load methods can instead be called in `setup()` or anywhere else with the use of a callback parameter.

An example of this is [on discourse](https://discourse.processing.org/t/loading-screen-with-preload/38917/2). Here's a modified version of that:

```js
let img;
let loaded = false;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1000, 1000);

  img = loadImage(
    `https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?cache=${random()}`,
    () => loaded = true
  );
}

function draw() {
  clear();

  if (loaded) {
    image(img, 0, 0);
  }
  else {
    background("red");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

If you have multiple assets to load, you could use a counter rather than a boolean to determine when they're all loaded.

Instead of using an `if`, you can also assign a different function to `window.draw` to run when the assets load, which is a bit simpler to maintain.